# How to include custom js file?

Tags: magento2

I want to add lazy load js file in custom module.

In templates folder in that web/js/lazy_load.js file I have put.

Then in layout file

```
  <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

<head>
    <title>Pest Library</title>
    <script src="js/jquery.lazyload.js"/>
</head> 

<body>

    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Iksula\PestLibrary\Block\Index\Index" name="pestlibrary_index_index" template="Iksula_PestLibrary::pestlibrary_index_index.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>

</body>
</page>
```

But js file is not called.

Comment: please let me know if you have issue.

Answer (score 2):

**If you want to add js in your custom module using layout then you need to write below code :**

```
 <head>
       <script src="Iksula_PestLibrary::js/jquery.lazyload.js"/> 
</head>
```

After that run **php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy** command

**But as per magento 2 standards use require-js concept to include js**

**Create requirejs-config.js in app/code/Iksula/PestLibrary/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

Below is the code using **requirejs-config.js** :

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            lazyloadScript:'Iksula_PestLibrary::js/jquery.lazyload'
        }
    }
};
```

then call js in your template file: **app/code/Vendorname/modulename/templates/custom_js.phtml**

```
<script>// <![CDATA[
    require([
        'jquery',
        'lazyloadScript'
    ], function ($, script) {
        //Your code here
        //alert('Here');
    });
    // ]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are forgot first line  and also assigned modulepath for your js file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <title>Pest Library</title>
    <script src="Iksula_PestLibrary::js/jquery.lazyload.js"/>
</head>
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Iksula\PestLibrary\Block\Index\Index" name="pestlibrary_index_index" template="Iksula_PestLibrary::pestlibrary_index_index.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

Run **php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy** command